# Blasor WASM error There is no registered service of type <MyApp.Services.MyService>

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, .net-5

I am creating a .Net 5 Blazor WASM non-hosted app. In this configuration there is only one project -- The client. We are told to register our services in `Program.cs` with this configuration which I have done like this `builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();` In `_Imports.razor` I also added `@using MyApp.Services`. In my component I have added `@inject Services.MyService MyService` and on the page component I have `<MyListComponent />` but I still get the following error when browsing to that page:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'MyService' on type 'MyApp.Shared.MyList'. There is no registered service of type 'MyApp.Services.MyService'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting by interface.

```
@inject IMyService MyService
```